# What are all the possible settings attributes in TinyMCE's addButton() function?

Tags: javascript, button, user-interface, tinymce, wysiwyg

The [documentation](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton) is not very clear on this.

> name - String - Button name to add.
>
> settings - Object - Settings object with title, cmd **etc**.

"etc"? Really? Where can I see the rest of the possible attributes?

Comment: Yea, i can't believe how ugly the tinyMCE documentation is... im here for the same thing... when i saw the "etc" there after 2 possible setting options i laughed so hard.

Comment: I thought I was the only one thinking this. The TinyMCE API documentation is absolutely atrocious.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

- `autofocus`: True if the control should be focused when rendered
- `border`: Border box values example: 1 1 1 1
- `classes`: Space separated list of classes to add
- `disabled`: Is the control disabled by default
- `hidden`: Is the control hidden by default
- `icon`: Icon to use for button
- `image`: Image to use for icon
- `margin`: Margin box values example: 1 1 1 1
- `minHeight`: Minimal height for the control
- `minWidth`: Minimal width for the control
- `name`: Name of the control instance
- `padding`: Padding box values example: 1 1 1 1
- `role`: WAI-ARIA role to use for control
- `size`: Size of the button small|medium|large
- `style`: Style CSS properties to add
- `text`: Text to display inside widget
- `tooltip`: Tooltip text to display when hovering

For a full list of all the settings and methods see the [TinyMCE documentation page](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4%3aclass.tinymce.ui.Button)

Comment: Where is "ui" in TinyMCE 4 now? It's gone, how can i switch or validate against that now?

Comment: Still seems to be there - http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:namespace.tinymce.ui

Comment: Any idea what goes into 'style'?

Comment: @bart - have a look here, http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:style_formats

Comment: There is a `type` option, however, I couldn't find any reference to all possible values for it in the official docs. BTW, the links above are broken. :/

Answer (score 18):

What you would like to know is what settings may fit into the settings object (tinymce 3).
Here it is:

```
title       --> title
label       --> label
scope       --> scope
onclick     --> function to be called onclick
menu_button --> flag, defines if the button is a menu button
cmd         --> tinymce command to get executed onClick
ui          --> paramter for the tinymce command cmd
value       --> value for the tinymce command cmd
```

Those settings get assigned in the function `createButton` of the class `ControlManager`.

Comment: this is certainly not complete; see answer below for more, Also not complete though!

Answer (score 6):

Having had the same issue trying to find the `addButton` docs in V4 I found the link, just in case anybody needs it.

[tinymce.ui.Button](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce.ui/tinymce.ui.button/)

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: It is not enough simply point to an external link. Your post should explain the answer possibly with an example and point to an external resource for more details.

Comment: Thank you! The only comment to has the actual link to the documentation for the settings object!

Comment: @Andy in that case read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer :-)